# Split line comma at end of line and exclude special cases

Tags: regex

Hi i have the following group:

```
`group_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`right_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`group__right_value` enum('allow','deny') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'deny',
KEY `group_id` (`group_id`),
KEY `right_id` (`right_id`)
```

And i expected the strings to always end with a comma so a did a split based on that. Now i've noticed that in some cases like above the commas should be ignored and the values left as they are:

```
enum('allow','deny')
```

How should i exclude the commas between brackets when doing the split?

EDIT:

The expected result should be:

1. 'group_id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
2. 'right_id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
3. 'group__right_value' enum('allow','deny') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'deny',
4. KEY 'group_id' ('group_id'),
5. KEY 'right_id' ('right_id')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matching a comma at the end of the string is done with an anchor:

```
/,$/m
```

The `/m` modifier is used to enable multiline mode, in which `$` will match the end of the line instead of the standard end-of-subject.

Answer (score 0):

http://regexr.com?3579s

Hope this help `[^\,]+(\,\')?[^\,]+`